# Get fully-qualified metadata name in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to get the full CLR name of a particular symbol. This means that for generic types I need the `` `1 ``, `` `2 ``, etc. appended to types. Now, `ISymbol` already has a property `MetadataName` which does exactly that. But it excludes surrounding types and namespaces, only giving the name of the symbol at hand.

The usual option for getting a fully-qualified name, i.e. via `ToDisplayString` doesn't quite work here because it will not use the `MetadataName` for its various parts.

Is there anything like this built-in? Or do I have to just concatenate the chain of `ContainingSymbol`s with `.` in between? (And are there points where this assumption breaks down?)

**EDIT:** Just noticed that you need a `+` in between individual names if it's a type contained in another type, but apart from that, using `.` should work, I guess.

Comment: Please support my Roslyn Issue on CodePlex for this feature: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/297

Comment: A Roslyn team member created an issue for this, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1891

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For now, having no better solution, I'm using the following:

```
public static string GetFullMetadataName(this ISymbol s) 
{
    if (s == null || IsRootNamespace(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder(s.MetadataName);
    var last = s;

    s = s.ContainingSymbol;

    while (!IsRootNamespace(s))
    {
        if (s is ITypeSymbol && last is ITypeSymbol)
        {
            sb.Insert(0, '+');
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Insert(0, '.');
        }

        sb.Insert(0, s.OriginalDefinition.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.MinimallyQualifiedFormat));
        //sb.Insert(0, s.MetadataName);
        s = s.ContainingSymbol;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

private static bool IsRootNamespace(ISymbol symbol) 
{
    INamespaceSymbol s = null;
    return ((s = symbol as INamespaceSymbol) != null) && s.IsGlobalNamespace;
}
```

which seems to work for now. Roslyn seems to have internal flags for `SymbolDisplayFormat` that enable that sort of thing (most notably [SymbolDisplayCompilerInternalOptions.UseArityForGenericTypes](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/SymbolDisplay/SymbolDisplayCompilerInternalOptions.cs,1cfcd6568bf43656,references), but not accessible to the outside.

Above code could probably be faster on recent .NET versions by using `Append` instead of `Insert` on the `StringBuilder`, but that's something to leave for profiling.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly enough, but doing `symbol.ToString()` actually worked for me. That gave me a fully-qualified name with the namespace etc.

Comment: It's not the metadata name, though, which shows nested types differently (`+`) and doesn't use the type parameter names, just the type parameter arity preceded with a backtick.

Comment: Good point, although I guess that would still work pretty well with namespace names...

Comment: This also doesn't take into account nested types