# Get full name of ITypeSymbol for nested type?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I've got an `ITypeSymbol` for a nested type (`MyNamespace.MyOuter.Nested`) and am trying to get the type's full name using:

```
typeSymbol.ToDisplayString(new SymbolDisplayFormat(
    SymbolDisplayGlobalNamespaceStyle.Omitted,
    SymbolDisplayTypeQualificationStyle.NameAndContainingTypesAndNamespaces,
    SymbolDisplayGenericsOptions.IncludeTypeParameters,
    miscellaneousOptions: SymbolDisplayMiscellaneousOptions.ExpandNullable
));
```

Reflection returns the full name as `MyNamespace.MyOuter+Nested` - how to obtain the very same string from Roslyn? The display format above returns `MyNamespace.MyOuter.Nested` :-(

Comment: `MyNamespace.MyOuter+Nested` is the **.NET/CIL** name, `MyNamespace.MyOuter.Nested` is the **C#** full name.

Comment: Is there a way to generate the .NET/CIL name with Roslyn?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But you can generate it yourself with the extension method shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105909/get-fully-qualified-metadata-name-in-roslyn