# Roslyn get all object creations and its identifier name

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am looking for a solution to get all object creations inside a method. I came up with following solution to get a list of all creations:

```
var creations = MethodDeclaration.Body.DescendantNodes().OfType<ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax>();
```

But now I am looking for the identifier name(variable name). While debugging I figured out, that this variable has this information - but the identifier property is no accessible.

```
creations.First().Parent.Parent.Identifier.ValueText;
```

So i would be very pleased if someone has a solution for my problem.

**EDIT**

I am trying to analyze unittests. E.g.:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WarningOverReferencedTest()
{
    var myVar = new MyObject();
    var myVar1 = new MyObject1();
    var myVar2 = new MyObject2();
    var myVar3 = new MyObject();
    var myVar4 = new MyObject3();
    Assert.AreEqual(true, myVar.someProperty);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, myVar3.someProperty2);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, myVar1.someProperty);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, myVar2.someProperty);
}
```

I want to count the references used in the `Assert.AreEqual` checks. So the example from above should return 3, because `myVar` and `myVar3` are from the same type and `myVar4` is not used in the `Assert.AreEqual` check.

Comment: I updated my answer, Marcel.

Comment: big big thanks so far. And how can i count those references from the edited example above?

Comment: It is in my answer. You can just call `types.Count` to get the count.

Comment: yes i know, but this is no 100 % correct, because i what only those types which where used in the assertions. I would get now 4 but it should be 3.

Comment: Well then look at the `Assert` method invocations, collect the `ITypeSymbol`-s from the parameter list and cross reference the two sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `creations.First().Parent.Parent` to a Type that has an `Identifier` property - in your case it's most likely `VariableDeclaratorSyntax` - then you will be able to access its `Identifier`. This is of course dangerous because you might find an `ObjectCreationSyntax` whose grandparent is different.

Take a look at this example:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>() {
      new Person("Jim"),
      new Person("Frank")
};
```

You'll successfully get the `Identifier` of the `people` `ObjectCreation`, but not its elements' (since they do not have a variable name at all). There are lots of corner cases to work around, with lots of possible solutions.

A dirty workaround would be to check if the grandparent is of kind `VariableDeclarator` and cast it only then. Maybe if you share what you are trying to accomplish (in the grand scheme of things) I can advice better.

**EDIT**

If I understood you correctly, you want to count the number of distinct types created in a method. `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` objects have a `Type` property, which shows what type of object is being created. This is exactly what you need, however getting the type itself is [troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371704/derive-parameter-type-with-roslyn/44383039#44383039), but you can look at the names like so:

```
HashSet<ITypeSymbol> types = new HashSet<ITypeSymbol>();

foreach (ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax node in creations)
{
    var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node).Type;
    types.Add(typeSymbol);
}
int numberOfTypes = types.Count;
```

You can't just count the `node.Type`-s, becuase those are `SyntaxNode`-s, and will not be identical. But their symbol will be, and using a `HashSet` will ensure that you are getting no duplicates. You can get the `SemanticModel` object from the context if you use `RegisterSemanticModelAction`.

Comment: `Type` is just the name of the type as it appears in source code, not the name of the actual type. Given your code, `string`, `String` and `System.String` would be considered different types. And then I'm not even talking about aliases such as `using Text = String;`. To cut a long story short, you should use the `SemanticModel` and call `GetTypeInfo` on the `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax`.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Indeed, and all that can be seen in the question I linked. The code I wrote was meant to be for the example he provided earlier (now gone). But you are right, I'll edit it soon.