# Roslyn CodeFix Provider (VS2015): How to get a class property/field type

Tags: types, properties, roslyn, codefixprovider

How can I get the data type of a property/field?
The only way that I'm able to do that is by searching in the syntax tree of the document where the class is stored. It's a bit slow and there's also the problem of inheritance (Need's to search other file, than another, etc). 
There's a limitation with my solution: In a solution with multi projects, it need's to have all projects loaded!

Is it possible to do something like:

```
Type mType = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.SampleClass");
```

Comment: Could you provide a short code sample that clarifies what exactly you have and what is the result that you want?

Comment: You're looking for the semantic model.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.gettypebymetadataname?view=roslyn-dotnet).

```
CodeFixContext context = ...
SemanticModel model = await context.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
Compilation compilation = model.Compilation;
INamedTypeSymbol symbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyNamespace.SampleClass");
```

You can't get a `System.Type` from a symbol--that's a reflection type, which [has nothing to do with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747260/getting-type-from-a-symbol-in-roslyn). You'll have to get by with an `INamedTypeSymbol`.

Comment: I only have the Class name, don't have the namespace (may be diferent of the actual one).  So to get the SampleClass name space I did: ISymbol mCompleteClassName = compilation.GetSymbolsWithName(x => x == "SampleClass")?.FirstOrDefault(); 
INamedTypeSymbol symbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName($"{mCompleteClassName}"); 

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you only have the type name, there could be multiple classes with that name. Your code will be faulty in that case--sometimes selecting the wrong type. You need the fully qualified name of a type in order to uniquely identify it. Can you add some information about what you are trying to accomplish? How did you determine the type name? How will you use the `INamedTypeSymbol`?